# Assigning new value to object field in await blocks further instructions

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter

I'm stuck on this, I have no clue why won't the last print execute past object value initialization.

```
await _client
      .get(Uri.parse(_url), headers: {"location": "Mars"})
      .then((result) => result.body)
      .then(json.decode)
      .then((json) => json.forEach((person) {
        print(person); // this gets executed and printed over and over
        Person newPerson;
        print('hehe lolz'); // this gets executed too
        newPerson.status = person['status'];
        print('hello'); // this never gets executed...
```

Person class is just a model with all String fields and a constructor.

What could be blocking the execution of last print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because newPerson is null and when you are trying to call newPerson.status - the NullPointer exception appears and all the code below doesn't execute. Just make:

```
Person newPerson = Person();
```

Comment: I wanted to argue that I tried with named constructor from my model before and it wouldn't work - but I tried this and it worked like a charm. Thanks man.